# Java thread stopping for a while

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, concurrency

I've the following problem. I've a Springboot Java app deployed in a tomcat server. I'm using SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor and @Scheduled to run some tasks every 10 min. But sometimes the execution just stops, and continues after a while, sometimes 2 minutes, sometimes 10, and sometimes it just doesn't continue the execution.

I've tried increasing the tomcat max memory, but this didn't work. Im sure it's not an uncaught exception, so I think it may be thread starvation, but how can I solve this?

Comment: can u share some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's thread starvation issue then you can use the keyword `synchronized`in your method declarations or create a `synchronized{}` block of code wherever there is critical code . Also you can use a `Lock` and use `.lock()` and `.unlock()` methods provided with `Lock`.

Note-if you are using `Lock` put your critical code in  a `try{} finally` block so you always release the intrinsic lock.

```
lock.lock();      //using lock 
        try {
            //execute critical section of the code.
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();//release the lock so other thread can use it.
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Were you able to take thread dumps when the execution is frozen? What do they show? To debug issues like this, I used to take a sequence of 5 thread dumps 5 to 10 seconds apart and analyze them with some thread dump analyzer tool like https://fastthread.io/

Answer (score 0):

Two things could be happening:

1. your threads are waiting for monitor
2. GC is doing stop-the-world collection.

You could add GC log to your application using -xloggc switch. That way you will have a better picture of your heap.

You can also take stack trace using jstack or kill -3 before , after and while the threads are locked up. You can run this separately and output to a file.

You could also connect jconsole to your application and examine your heap and threads